# Remote AD session error trapping woes

Tags: session, powershell

I am trying to catch exceptions in my remote PoSH script and I'm getting different behaviour depending on whether it is a local or remote PoSH session.  The first code works as expected, the user cannot be enabled because it has no password and thus is caught by the ADPasswordComplexityException catch.

import-module activedirectory

```
try { Set-ADUser user123 -ErrorAction "stop" -Enabled $true  } 
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPasswordComplexityException] { write-host "gotya" } 
catch { write-host "err" }
```

..resulting in gotya being written.  This happens whether I run the code locally on the DC or another PC.  So all good there.

However when doing this via a remote session not only the initial catch does not work, neither does the second catch..

```
$ADS = New-PSSession -computername dc.domain -Authentication default -Credential $(get-credential)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -PSSession $ADS   

try { Set-ADUser user123 -ErrorAction "stop" -Enabled $true  } 
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPasswordComplexityException] { write-host "gotya" } 
catch { write-host "err" }
```

When run remotely it returns (presumably skipping all catches):

```
The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (user123:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADPasswordComplexityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the etc..
```

Also when I run the remote script locally on the DC oddly I get a different error:

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPasswordComplexityException]: make sure that the assembly
containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:7
+ try { Set-ADUser -ErrorAction "stop" user123 -Enabled $true  }
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Activ...lexityException:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Any ideas why PoSH hates me?  thanks in advance.